# Is there any way to get notified if an iOS system popover disappears?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, popover, airplay

In the concrete case I'm referring to the airplay popover where you can choose between your iOS device, all available airplay devices and the cancel button. I need to know when the popover disappears in order to do some further actions. Is there any possibility to accomplish that?

Comment: Can we see some code where you create the button or interface that you're referring to? How is the popover managed?

Answer (score 1):

Does UIPopoverControllerDelegate's `-popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:` method do what you need?